# how to display table rows in html table using asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am using mysql database. in my mysql table, columns are c_name, c_number, c_mail and c_address. I want to show this table in html table. My asp.net code is below.

```
        dbConnection.Open();
        String str = "select c_name, c_number, c_mail, c_address from contacts where user_id = "+user_id+"";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, dbConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (mdr.Read())
        {
            cname = mdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
```

Please Help me. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `GridView`.

Add a `GridView` to your page and in your code behind just assign the `DataReader` you already have to this `GridView`'s `DataSource` property.

```
dbConnection.Open();
        String str = "select c_name, c_number, c_mail, c_address from contacts where user_id = "+user_id+"";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, dbConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);


GridView1.DataSource = MySqlDataReader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

User [Gridview](http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/asp-gridview.htm) or [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx) instead.

Some examples of repeater
http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

If you still want to use `HtmlTable` then you can use the classes which are available in asp.net.

```
Table tbl = new Table();
TableRow tr = null;
TableCell cell = null;

.......
.......
panel.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

You need to use the following namespace `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;`

Some similar question on SO

1. [Show data in ASP.NET html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860490/show-data-in-asp-net-html-table)
2. [Putting data from SqlDataReader into HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067119/putting-data-from-sqldatareader-into-html-table)